# Why do tags disappear when adding '; ' to field which is combined with 'for xml path'?

Tags: sql-server

I want to concatenate some values from a sub-query into a string. But something happens I do not understand.

When I use this sql:

```
select (
    select t1.value 
--       + '; '
    from Table1 t1
        join Table2 t2 on t1.xId=t2.xId and t1.TypeId in (31,33)
    where t2.pId=1001
    for xml PATH('')
)
as ValuesAsString
```

I get:

```
<value>value 1</value><value>value 2</value>
```

But when I remove the '--' and run the query again, the output becomes:

```
value 1; value 2;
```

Why are the xml tags removed?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the inner query without the XML functionality. In the original query, it produces a result set with a single column called `value`, because you're directly selecting from a column called `value`.

In the updated query, you get a result set with a single *unnamed* column, because you're selecting an *expression* value.

So the tag names are based on the column names (or any applied aliases), and in the updated example, the column has no name. And since there's no way to have an unnamed element in XML, the element tags are omitted.

```
select (
    select t1.value 
       + '; ' as fruitbat
    from Table1 t1
        join Table2 t2 on t1.xId=t2.xId and t1.TypeId in (31,33)
    where t2.pId=1001
    for xml PATH('')
)
as ValuesAsString
```

Would produce XML with your values enclosed in `<fruitbat>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because the name of the column is used as the element-name in a `FOR XML PATH('')`. When you have a computed expression and you don't supply a column alias (`... AS alias_name`, or `alias_name=...`), a column name does not exist so no element-name is renderered (an empty XML element name is invalid).

To remove the column name, select the column as the `[text()]` property, like

```
...
select [text()]=t1.value
...
```

---

More info: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35172160/243373), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31211506/243373).