# applying concat function on one column values to get data from another table

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

table :

```
value  
- v1  
- v2
```

Now , I need to apply concat function on value col

```sql
concat(v1 , ' ' , v2)
```

like this.

I have used `concat()` on two or more col values but not on rows of one column.

How should I do it?

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: i tried string_agg on the col first and then try applying concat but that gives error as it will consider that as one value

Comment: what version of SQL server are you running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How FOR XML PATH('') works when concatenating rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148472/how-for-xml-path-works-when-concatenating-rows)

Comment: sample data :
level                new_value
TRADING_COMPANY      TRADING_COMPANY 
TRADING_COMPANY      PRODUCT_RANGE

result :

concat (TRADING_COMPANY , ' ' , PRODUCT_RANGE)

Comment: tried this first :STRING_AGG(value, ' , ') as new_value but can't apply concat on new_value

Answer (score 0):

You may use `STUFF` for your solution.

```
 select stuff( (select ',' + column from table for xml path('')), 1,1,'')
```