# What is "STUFF AND FOR XML PATH" used for?

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-path

There are bulk of sites providing information on STUFF AND FOR XML PATH but I want to know the actual use and where it can be implemented.

Please guide

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sno,
    STUFF ((SELECT ','+Scity
            FROM @abcdef T1
            WHERE T1.sno = T2.sno
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM
    @abcdef T2
```

Now in the example above please tell me what are those quotes and 1,1 used for.

Comment: it will just delete and replace those xml tags

Comment: oops! sorry I forgot to mention I am using it in sql server. I will edit my question. SO , it will get clear to you

Comment: Did you look at the documentation at all? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: In this case STUFF just deletes first comma. Replace first symbol (comma) with empty string.

Comment: Here's a reasonable explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35172160/243373

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is an idiomatic way of producing a CSV in T-SQL. If you're on a version of SQL Server that supports `STRING_AGG()` (SQL 2017+ iirc), then use that.